# How to parse the output string of a child process created by "CreateProcess"

Tags: c, windows, winapi

I execute an .exe within my code. Like:

```
if( !CreateProcess( NULL,   // No module name (use command line)
    "sub.exe 2",    // Command line
    NULL,           // Process handle not inheritable
    NULL,           // Thread handle not inheritable
    FALSE,          // Set handle inheritance to FALSE
    0,              // No creation flags
    NULL,           // Use parent's environment block
    NULL,           // Use parent's starting directory 
    &si,            // Pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
    &pi )           // Pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION structure
)
```

The sub.exe multiplies simply the given value with 3. So that I should get a 6

How do I get the responded string to work with in my further code?

Comment: Please provide a code fragment that has been compiled and tested at least once.  The code you have provided, specifically the parameter `sub.exe 2` does not appear to have been tested.

Comment: Create a pipe using `CreatePipe()` and set them up in the `STARTUPINFO` structure (`si` in your case).  You can then read from the pipe to get the process output.

Comment: @Jack: It has been tested. Only instead of sub.exe 2 there was a "buffer" variable so I changed it for better readability.

Answer (score 2):

See these Microsoft samples on how to capture the standard output and error via pipes:

- [Creating a Child Process with Redirected Input and Output](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682499%28VS.85%29.aspx)
- [How to spawn console processes with redirected standard handles](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/190351)